# IOS-Unable to create framework for Reachability with class name changed.

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create a framework for Reachability with the class name being changed.
The source code is available here..

> [Reachability Source code](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

I download the code and then open the Framework.xcodeproj after that,i change the Reachability class name by using Xcode's Refactor and also change the products name in info.plist build settings so that it becomes MReachability.framework and then i build it for profiling and debugging.

I then copy MReachability.framework from release folder and import it in my project.
Everything works like expected till here.But when i run my program,it crashes at the start with following error..

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Reachability.framework/Reachability
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2BF038FD-AD41-40DF-9EAB-3D490F76764E/TestApp.app/TestApp
  Reason: image not found
```

I don't get it,why is it still trying to find Reachability.framework/Reachability?
It should be MReachability.
I know,i am missing something really stupid while creating the framework.

Below is an image,which shows the changes that,i am making.

> [Image of Changes in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YghxQ.png)

Thank you!